# MailChimp API - oauth2 access_token request error

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, httprequest, mailchimp-api-v3.0, request-promise

I'm using mailchimp api https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/how-to-use-oauth2/ to authorise my app using oAuth2.
I can successfully retrieve access_code but when I make a request to https://login.mailchimp.com/oauth2/token
to exchange it to access_token I get 400 error.

I'm using Request-Promise library https://github.com/request/request-promise

```
 const data ="grant_type=authorization_code" +
         "&client_id="+ constants.CLIENT_ID +
         "&client_secret=" + constants.CLIENT_SECRET +
         "&redirect_uri=" + encodeURIComponent(redirect_uri)+
         "&code=" + 'access_code';

 request({
        method: 'POST',
        uri: 'https://login.mailchimp.com/oauth2/token',
        body: data
    });
```

I have tried to send it as a JSON object but to no avail. I assume that body should contain a string. 
Sample Curl request example from the docs

```
curl --request POST \
--url 'https://login.mailchimp.com/oauth2/token' \
--data "grant_type=authorization_code&client_id= {client_id}&client_secret={client_secret}&redirect_uri={encoded_url}&code={code}" \
```

--include

Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm having the same exact issue.  I can't even send the curl request from their docs.  Did you find a solution?

Comment: Yes. My redirect url was different than initially declared on mailchimp api. It was 127.0.0.1 and I was using localhost instead.